# JBOSS Login with Oracle DBMS: No matching username found in Principals

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jboss

i have a Problem with the Login to my Java Application on JBOSS.
I use the Database Login Module with JBOSS 7.1.1
The test enviroment was on a MySQL Database. Everything worked great and without Problems. The Application deployed correctly and i could login to my application.
Now for production, the DBMS have to be changed to Oracle. Also here everything deployed. I could open the Application with my Browser. But no login is possible. Everytime i tried to login myself, the log says: `PB00019: Processing Failed:No matching username found in Principals`.
This is my configuration for the login module:

```
<security-domain name="apdomainhashed" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWORD FROM TBLUSERS WHERE USERNAME=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT r.rolename, 'Roles' FROM TBLUSERS u INNER JOIN TBLUSER_GROUPS ug ON u.id = ug.users_id INNER JOIN TBLGROUPS g ON g.id = ug.groups_id INNER JOIN TBLGROUPS_ROLES gr ON gr.groups_id = g.id INNER JOIN TBLROLES r ON r.id = gr.roles_id WHERE u.username=? AND u.active=1"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-512"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="BASE64"/>
                            <module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="false"/>
                            <module-option name="hashUserPassword" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="passwordIsA1Hash" value="true"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

If i send the query by hand, i receive the correct value:

```
SELECT PASSWORD FROM TBLUSERS WHERE USERNAME='admin';

PASSWORD
----------
c0jKLdIKuAJCrwhcmV4dkZftUWIiv1iT51Oupznz730D8+WGVoSh2j/Ou79p1L9H8YyLB1Ssrbbd\nG2D0ZSBmvw==
```

This is the complete Trace of the failed login:

```
07:44:31,291 TRACE [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Begin isValid, principal:admin, cache entry: null
07:44:31,292 TRACE [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) defaultLogin, principal=admin
07:44:31,292 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfigImpl] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Begin getAppConfigurationEntry(apdomainhashed), size=4
07:44:31,293 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfigImpl] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) End getAppConfigurationEntry(apdomainhashed), authInfo=AppConfigurationEntry[]:
[0]
LoginModule Class: org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: required
Options:
name=hashUserPassword, value=true
name=hashAlgorithm, value=SHA-512
name=principalsQuery, value=SELECT PASSWORD FROM TBLUSERS WHERE USERNAME=?
name=passwordIsA1Hash, value=true
name=hashEncoding, value=BASE64
name=dsJndiName, value=java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS
name=hashStorePassword, value=false
name=rolesQuery, value=SELECT r.rolename, 'Roles' FROM TBLUSERS u INNER JOIN TBLUSER_GROUPS ug ON u.id = ug.users_id INNER JOIN TBLGROUPS g ON g.id = ug.groups_id INNER JOIN TBLGROUPS_ROLES gr ON gr.groups_id = g.id INNER JOIN TBLROLES r ON r.id = gr.roles_id WHERE u.username=? AND u.active=1

07:44:31,296 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) initialize
07:44:31,297 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Security domain: apdomainhashed
07:44:31,297 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Password hashing activated: algorithm = SHA-512, encoding = BASE64, charset = {default}, callback = null, storeCallback = null
07:44:31,298 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) DatabaseServerLoginModule, dsJndiName=java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS
07:44:31,299 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) principalsQuery=SELECT PASSWORD FROM TBLUSERS WHERE USERNAME=?
07:44:31,299 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) rolesQuery=SELECT r.rolename, 'Roles' FROM TBLUSERS u INNER JOIN TBLUSER_GROUPS ug ON u.id = ug.users_id INNER JOIN TBLGROUPS g ON g.id = ug.groups_id INNER JOIN TBLGROUPS_ROLES gr ON gr.groups_id = g.id INNER JOIN TBLROLES r ON r.id = gr.roles_id WHERE u.username=? AND u.active=1
07:44:31,301 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) suspendResume=true
07:44:31,302 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) login
07:44:31,303 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) suspendAnyTransaction
07:44:31,304 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Excuting query: SELECT PASSWORD FROM TBLUSERS WHERE USERNAME=?, with username: admin
07:44:31,305 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Query returned no matches from db
07:44:31,306 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) resumeAnyTransaction
07:44:31,306 TRACE [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) abort
07:44:31,307 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PB00019: Processing Failed:No matching username found in Principals
```

Under MySQL the Datatype of the column was VARCHAR. With oracle now it's VARCHAR2.

Does anybody know why i couldn't login with oracle as datasource?

Answer (score 1):

You use "java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" JNDI name everywhere.
Is there the old datasource specified or it is the old name is still there?
Other words, is MySqlDS actually specifies connection to Oracle?

Comment: Then you could try to temporarily rename TBL_USERS to _TBL_USERS for example and you will see if query runs on appropriate DB or not. I suppose it is occasionally not.